# Saving files with cv2.imwrite() making the output white completely after FFT conversion

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to denoise images using `Fast Fourier Transformation (FFT)`  in python using the reference from [this site](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_transforms/py_fourier_transform/py_fourier_transform.html). Unfortunately my output image is becoming completely white. However, plotting them using matplotlib perfectly outputs! I do not know much about denoising. Any other suggestion is also welcome to properly denoise image. Could someone please help?

Follwoing is the code

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('sample.png',0)
img_float32 = np.float32(img)
dft = cv2.dft(img_float32, flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
rows, cols = img.shape
crow, ccol = rows//2 , cols//2     # center

# create a mask first, center square is 1, remaining all zeros
mask = np.zeros((rows, cols, 2), np.uint8)
mask[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 1

# apply mask and inverse DFT
fshift = dft_shift*mask
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift)
img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0],img_back[:,:,1])
cv2.imwrite('conv_sample.png', img_back)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img_back, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Here is the input (`sample.png`) image

[image]

this is the output (`sample.png`) image (completely white!)

[image]

and here is the plot comparing two images

[image]

I am trying to save an image like the right one in the plot or with a better one. Thank you.

Comment: please provide the data required for a [mre].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz could you please check now? thank you.

Comment: wait, _that_ is the input? wow! anyway, you missed the `DFT_SCALE` flag. pass it to exactly one of dft or idft. and I would **not recommend** mixing the dft/fft of OpenCV and numpy. for DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT it seems to be okay...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you, it worked! just have another question, I am working with gravity wave data that contains lots of lights (the brighter portions in the image) on the earth which are most troubled noise for my images. any suggestions to reduce such noise please? I am new in image denoising. thanks again.

Comment: image formation is critical. you have saturated areas. make sure to not saturate your sensor, or whatever you use to make these pictures.